# How to have linked axes on plots?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot

I plot infrared spectra in many reports and I display the energy units in two ways, wavenumbers `$cm^{-1}$` on the bottom x-axis and wavelength (nm) on the upper x-axis. The relationship is
    `X(nm)=1e7/Y(cm^{-1})`.

for example a spectra running from `4000$cm^{-1}$-400$cm^{-1}$` on the bottom x-axis (a linear scale) corresponds to a wavelength range of 2500nm - 25,000nm a non-linear scale.
Is there a way to have this done in pgf, tikz etc? I use Origin to do this and then export as pdf and use
    `\includegraphics{linked-axis-plot.pdf}`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use PGFplots for this. To get a second x-axis, you have to overlay the original plot with a second one of equal dimension that contains only the secondary axis. I've written a style called `master axis` that calculates and saves the equivalent horizontal dimensions needed for the secondary axis, which in turn uses the style `secondary axis` to read and set the dimensions.

[image: IR plot with linked axes]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{siunitx} % For typesetting of units

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfkeys{/pgfplots/.cd,master axis/.style={
    scale only axis,
    enlarge x limits=false,
    x dir=reverse,axis x line*=bottom,
    xticklabel shift=3pt,
    after end axis/.code={
      \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}
      \pgfmathparse{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}}
      \global\let\masterxmin=\pgfmathresult
      \pgfmathparse{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax}}
      \global\let\masterxmax=\pgfmathresult
      \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}
    }
  },
  slave axis/.style={
    scale only axis,enlarge x limits=false,
     x dir=reverse,
    axis x line*=top,
    axis y line=none,
    xmin=\masterxmin,xmax=\masterxmax,ymin=0,ymax=1,
    scaled x ticks=false,
    xtick={100,400,1000,2000,4000,10000},
    xticklabel={
      \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu}
      \pgfmathparse{1e7/\tick}
      \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}
    }
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[master axis,
  ymin=0,ymax=100,
  xmin=400,xmax=4000,
  enlarge x limits=false, yticklabel={\SI[round-mode=places,round-precision=0]{\tick}{\percent}}, xlabel=Wavenumber / \si{\per\centi\metre},
  ylabel=Transmissivity
]
\addplot[domain=400:4000,samples=100,thick]{-(abs(tan(x/10))-2*rnd)+90};
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[slave axis,xlabel=Wavelength / \si{\nano\metre}]\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Jake: The image you have put up is what I am looking for unfortunately when I cut and paste the above code into my editor and run it (MiKTeX2.9, Texmaker) I get a series of errors (101 of them, all based on line 44 and 45 of the above code) mainly pgfplots errors etc. Did you have these errors? eg    ! Paragraph ended before \pgfmathfloatparse@@ was complete.
<to be read again>
\par
l.44

Comment: @Jake: The errors disappeared when I use an explicit x-range in the slave axis. `\begin{axis}[slave axis,xmin=\masterxmin,xmax=\masterxmax,ymin=0,ymax=1, xlabel=Wavelength / \si{\nano\metre}]\end{axis}` so thanks for your help and I have accepted the answer

Comment: With the current version of pgfplots (1.5.1) this now also works without providing `xmin` and `xmax` explicitly.