# Two different scales on stacked barplot

Tags: pgfplots

What I want to plot

I'd like to plot several stacked xbar plots where each bar plot contains two values. The total from each xbar-plot is based on one unit, i.e. the smallest bar represents "1" while the other are a multiple from this plot, e.g. 2 or 2.5 etc.
The two values per stacked plot are then percentages, i.e. 80% and 20%.

The problem

On the X axis I want the scale from 0 to the max value with one axis for all plots.
On each stacked plot I want to plot a scale ranging from 0% to 100%. The problem is: I can either plot only the absolute value on the X-axis or have the percentages per bar plot but not a mixture.

I want to know if there is a way to set something like a local coordinate system for each bar-plot. Or any hint to set the min and max value for the scale  of a bar-plot. Or, a way hoe I can multiply the ticks from the percentages by the scaling factor.

My code so far:

```
%% my preamble
    \documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
                \pgfplotsset{compat=1.5.1}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing, 
                            calc, 
                            matrix, 
                            positioning,
                            pgfplots.dateplot,
                            shapes.geometric,
                            shapes.misc,
                            shapes.arrows,
                            shapes.symbols
                           }

\begin{tikzpicture}
   \pgfplotsset{ 
    every linear axis/.append style = 
    {
     width = 3cm,
     font = \scriptsize, 
     %scale only axis  %% uncommenting this results scales percentage over  
                       %% absolute value: not desired
    },
    stacked/.style = 
    { 
    xbar stacked, 
    bar width   = 5pt,
    axis y line = none,
    xmin =  0, 
    xmax = 40, %% largest value, needed to set absolute max
    scale only axis  %% commenting this results in too short percentage  
                     %% scales
    },
    percent/.style = 
    {
    xmin =   1,
    ymin =   0,
    ymax =   1,
    axis y line  = none,
    axis x line* = top,
    yshift = 0.5cm,
    }
   }

    \begin{scope}[yshift = 4.75cm, xshift = 7cm]
     \begin{axis}[stacked, axis x line = none]
         \addplot coordinates { (14.45, 0) };  
         \addplot coordinates { ( 2.55, 0) };
       \end{axis}

     \begin{axis}
       [percent, xmax = 17,
        x coord trafo/.code= %% routine to transform absolute values into 
                             %% percentages
        {
         \pgfmathparse{#1 / 17 * 100}
        }]
      \end{axis}
    \end{scope} 

    %% almost the same as above. However, using the last entry to plot  
    %% absolute X-axis
    \begin{scope}[yshift = 2.5cm, xshift = 7cm]
       \begin{axis}[stacked, xmax = 40, axis x line* = bottom]
         \addplot coordinates{ (32, 0) };  
         \addplot coordinates{ ( 8, 0) };
       \end{axis}
       \begin{axis}[percent, xmax = 40,
        x coord trafo/.code=
        {
         \pgfmathparse{#1 / 40 * 100}
        }]
     \end{axis}
    \end{scope}
```

Comment: Maybe the answer to this question [How to have linked axes on plots](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18847/how-to-have-linked-axes-on-plots) may provide some help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of using a second `axis` environment for the secondary axis, you could make use of the `extra x ticks`. Here's a `.code` key that adds a percentage scale at the top of the plot. You don't need to supply the maximum value.

[image]

An alternative (that I would personally prefer) could be to add the percentage value to each bar segment. You can place nodes near the bars using `nodes near coords`, and calculate the percentages using `\pgfmathparse{100*\pgfplotspointmeta/\pgfplots@axiswide@metamax}`. This makes it easier to read the actual percentage value from the plot.

[image]

---

**Code for plot with two x axes**

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\makeatletter
\pgfplotsset{
    compat=1.5.1,
    percentage ticks/.style={
        before end axis/.code=\pgfplotsset{percentage ticks code}
    },
    percentage ticks code/.code={
        \pgfmathfloattofixed{\pgfplots@axiswide@metamax}
        \edef\pgfplotsaxiswidemetamax{\pgfmathresult}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\step{\pgfplotsaxiswidemetamax/4}
        \pgfplotsset{
            xtick pos=left,
            xlabel=Units,
            extra description/.code={
                \node [yshift=3ex, anchor=south] at (rel axis cs:0.5,1) {\%};
            },
            extra x ticks={0,\step,...,\pgfplotsaxiswidemetamax},
            extra x tick labels={0,25,...,100},
            extra x tick style={
                xtick pos=right,
                xticklabel pos=right
            }
        }
    }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xbar stacked,
    xmin=0,
    y=1cm,
    hide y axis,
    enlargelimits=false,
    percentage ticks
]
\addplot coordinates { (14.45, 0) };  
\addplot coordinates { ( 2.55, 0) };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

**Code for plot with labels for each bar**

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\makeatletter
\pgfplotsset{
    compat=1.5.1,
    percentage ticks/.code={
        \pgfplotsset{
            xtick pos=left,
            axis x line*=left,
            xlabel=Units,
            nodes near coords={
                \pgfkeys{
                    /pgf/fpu=true,  % PGFplots uses floating points internally
                    /pgf/fpu/output format=fixed
                }
                \pgfmathparse{100*\pgfplotspointmeta/\pgfplots@axiswide@metamax}
                \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}\,\%
            },
            every node near coord/.append style={yshift=1ex}
        }
    }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xbar stacked,
    xmin=0,
    y=0.5cm,
    hide y axis,
    percentage ticks,
    enlargelimits=false
]
\addplot coordinates { (14.45, 0) };  
\addplot coordinates { ( 2.55, 0) };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: sorry for the late reply and thx a lot for this solution. It works and I'll implement it in a a bigger scale as soon as possible. As mentioned, your second version is actually much nicer.