# How to have a date axis and a "normal" one linked on a plot?

Tags: pgfplots, axis, dateplot

I am plotting some date-based data with `pgfplots` where the date is on the x axis, which works so far (see MWE below). However, I would like to have a second x axis which is linked to the first one such that it reads days or weeks relative to a specific date, as annotated in red in the attached example output.

I somehow have the feeling that this could be achieved in analogy to [How to have linked axes on plots?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18847/how-to-have-linked-axes-on-plots) but I don't get the entry point where the calendar calculation part comes into play.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{data.dat}
date;value
2018-06-02;10
2018-06-04;12
2018-06-05;13
2018-06-06;10
2018-06-11;11
2018-07-30;15
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfcalendar}    % <-- to convert the dates to Julian integers
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}  % <-- to manipulate the data file/table
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=semicolon]{data.dat}\data
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            date coordinates in=x,
            xtick distance = 28,
            minor x tick num = 3]
            \addplot+ [only marks] table [x=date,y=value] {\data};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an idea. Use `\pgfcalendardatetojulian` to convert a `yyyy-mm-dd` to a Julian day. Define a day zero, and calculate the Julian day of this. Then use `xticklabel` (not `xticklabels`) where `\year`, `\month`, `\day` are available, and calculate the Julian day of each tick. Finally use `\inteval` from `xfp` to subtract the zero day from the tick day and print the result.

See also some comments in the code.

[image]

```
\begin{filecontents*}{data.dat}
date;value
2018-06-02;10
2018-06-04;12
2018-06-05;13
2018-06-06;10
2018-06-11;11
2018-07-30;15
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{xfp} % for \inteval
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}  % loads pgfplots which loads tikz which loads pgfcalendar
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=semicolon]{data.dat}\data
\begin{document}
\newcount\zeroday
\newcount\tickday
\pgfcalendardatetojulian{2018-06-01}{\zeroday}  % define a day zero

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    date coordinates in=x,
    xmin=2018-06-01, % to ensure same range, set xmin/xmax for both axes
    xmax=2018-07-30,
    xtick distance = 28,
    minor x tick num = 3,
]
   \addplot+ [only marks] table [x=date,y=value] {\data};
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[
    date coordinates in=x,
    xmin=2018-06-01,
    xmax=2018-07-30,
    xtick distance=7,
    xticklabel={
      \pgfcalendardatetojulian{\year-\month-\day}{\tickday} % calculate julian day
      \inteval{\the\tickday-\the\zeroday} % subtract the zero-day, prints result
    },
    xtick pos=top,
    axis y line=none
]

     \addplot [draw=none] coordinates {(2018-06-02,10)}; % have to plot something

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```